# Update query gives Mariadb version error

Tags: php, mariadb

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {

   $column=(isset( $_POST['column']));

   $type= (isset($_POST['type']));

   $value= (isset($_POST['value']));

   mysql_query("UPDATE `combo1` SET column = '$column', type = '$type' ,value ='$value' WHERE id = '$id'");
}
```

The update query is not working I am not getting what is the solution please help me to overcome this problem

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'column = '', type = '' ,value ='' WHERE id = '20'' at line 1

Comment: It's clear you are not getting variable's value

Comment: I'm not getting your point please explain in detail

Comment: You are getting blank values for `$column` , `$type` and `$value`

Comment: no getting previous value but those values are not updating to new value i.e. what we will give

Answer (score 0):

`isset()` method returns boolean value change like this

```
 $column = isset( $_POST['column']) ? $_POST['column']:"";
```

Same for others

Comment: Thanks for your effort and quick response but this code is not working for me, I think here problem is there with update query .....

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'column = '', type = '' ,value ='' WHERE id = '20'' at line 1

Comment: @shrutiAkki : please share source of posting data? Actually you are not getting values.

Comment: $ins="INSERT INTO `idcard`.`combo1`
(`column`, `type`, `value`) VALUES ('$column', '$type', 
'$value')";
$test=mysqli_query($link,$ins) or die(mysqli_error($link));
if($test)
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('submitted successfully!')</script>";
else
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('failed!')</script>";
}

Comment: $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM combo1 WHERE id = '$id'");
$test = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if (!$result) 
  {
  die("Error: Data not found..");
  }
          
         $column= $test['column'];
         $type= $test['type'];
         $value= $test['value'];
         
    if (isset($_POST['update'])) {

   $column = $_POST['column'];
   $type = $_POST['type'];
   $value = $_POST['value'];

   mysql_query("UPDATE `combo1` SET column = '$column', type = '$type' ,value ='$value' WHERE id = '$id'");
header("Location:excombo.php");

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code as follows:

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {

   $column = $_POST['column'];
   $type = $_POST['type'];
   $value = $_POST['value'];

   mysql_query("UPDATE `combo1` SET column = '$column', type = '$type' ,value ='$value' WHERE id = '$id'");
}
```

If you remove the `isset()` method (refer to this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) if you want more about the `isset()` method) as I have given above, the texts inside `$column`, `$type` and `$value` are substituted directly into the update string.

Update string does not contain any syntax errors in this case. Refer to this [link](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99/update-examples/) if you want more information.

I also recommend you read up on [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), as this sort of parameter passing is prone to hacking attempts if you do not sanitize the data being used:
[MySQL - SQL Injection Prevention](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php)

Comment: @yasgum :error message is not coming but values are not updating

Comment: Try `echo '$id';`, `echo '$column';` `echo '$type';` and `echo '$value';` just before the `mysql_query()` call to check whether they are empty.

Comment: It is good if you can upload your code to Github and give us the link. It will be helpful to identify the exact issue. And I highly recommend you to go through the documentations carefully.

Comment: yaa  i think  values are taking as empty  within update condition its not showing any value but only id is displaying

Answer (score 0):

The error message has virtually nothing to do with the 'version'.  It is a syntax error complaining about "column".  That word is a [*reserved word*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/reserved-words/).  Since you seem to have called the column `column`, put backtics around it, just as you did for the tablename.

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE `combo1` SET `column`='$column',`type` = '$type',`value`='$value' WHERE `id` ='$id'") 
or die(mysqli_error($link));